# webAPI serialise enums to strings

Tags: webapi

This doesn't do it

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum Numbers
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "[")]
        One,
        [EnumMember(Value = "Two")]
        Two

    }
```

And nor does this on the POCO/DTO.

```
        [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
        public IEnumerable<Numbers> Numbers{ get; set; }
```

Why is this impossible?

Comment: Are you using Json.net or the built in json serializer in .NET Core 3.1?

Comment: It's just out-of-the-box.

Comment: Then it looks to me as you're using Json.NET attributes, but if you use the out of the box Json serializer built into .NET Core 3.1, it won't recognize those attributes.

Comment: Can I deduce from this that the solution will be either to use some different attributes or to change the JSON thingy to Newtonsoft? Do you know whether either of these is possible? How?

Comment: You can change to json.net, I just don't know the exact method to call. I also believe you can get the same feature in the built in Json serializer, but again I don't know the exact attributes or method.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that out of the box it uses some JSON thing that *isn't* `Newtonsoft` and which ignores the `Newtonsoft` attributes. How very crap.

The fix is to install NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` and in `Startup.ConfigureServices` to add:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```